# Floating images in css

Tags: css

The following html and css format arranges my images so that there are nine on each row through floating.  There is, however, a large gap at the end of the each row (but presumably not large enough to fit another image, and thus the new row starts):

HTML:

```
<div id = "body">

<div class="img">
  <a href="">
  <img src="" width="110" height="90">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a href="">
  <img src="" width="110" height="90">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"></div>
</div>
</div>

//This is repeated many times so that there are 4 rows of nine images
```

CSS:

```
div.img
  {
  margin:2px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  }
div.img img
  {
  display:inline;
  margin:8px;
  }

div.desc
  {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:normal;
  width:120px;
  margin:5px;
  }
```

My first question is how do i "shift" the first image of each row so that gallery is symmetrical in the screen.  My second question concerns how to ensure this formation (9x4) is the same in every browser ( on every screen width)?

At present i have been using a fixed container (in terms of pixels) to fill my own screen.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: enclose all the image div's under a div. Add Margin property to the newly added div

Comment: Apply new divs just to the first image of each row i suppose?  Any idea about my second question?

Comment: No.enclose all the nine image div's under a new div and add margin-left to the newly added div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `float: left`, use `display: inline-block` on the container divs. This allows you to center the images:

```
#body {
  text-align: center;            
}
div.img
{
  display: inline-block;
  ....
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzH7R/1/

Comment: Wonderful - a very tidy solution!  Am i right in thinking this would also solve the multi-browser (my second question) concern as well?  Should do right?

Comment: Yeah, that is, the images fill the available width. If a browser is wider or smaller, you may get 10 or 8 or even 3 images in a row. Just as many as fits, and each row is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the divs inside one parent div (or 4 parent divs for each row and one above all).
For the inner divs, give position as absolute so that they are relative to the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding-left in the outer container to move the first image a bit to the right.

You have to specify all the sizes in percentage so that the screen scales properly in different resolutions.

The best way is to give different color borders for each element (div, img etc) and see how these borders align with each other.